# Input zero bytes to C program via argv

Tags: python, c, security, memory, argv

Here is the simple C prog

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int hex;
        memcpy(&hex, argv[1], 4);
        printf("hex %x\n", hex);
        return 0;
}
```

I have made the following experiment

```
./main `python -c 'print "\x01\x01\x02\x01"'`
```

The output was predictable: `hex 1020101`

Next i tried to put some zero bytes in my input

```
./main `python -c 'print "\x01\x00\x02\x01"'`
```

The output was a surprise for me

```
hex 10201
```

Then i checked what python exactly outputs to main input:

```
python -c 'print "\x01\x00\x02\x01"' > test
hexdump -C test

00000000  01 00 02 01 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```

And it seems python honestly put \x01\x00\x02\x01 to file and print end of line symbol.
My understanding is that argv[1] should be a pointer to memory where bytes pattern 01000201 is placed. And in this case output should be 1020001 but not 10201.

The question  - where is the zero byte?

Comment: By using the backticks you are passing the argument to the shell. So the zero byte never gets passed on, because the `\0` is the string terminator. So you are basically access uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero byte is the string terminator, so it never gets passed on by the *shell* when using the backticks. I'm pretty sure the kernel does not pass on any bytes after the first zero, either, because how should it know the actual length of the argument to copy?

You can easily verify this by

```
echo `python -c 'print "\x01\x00\x02\x01"'` | hd
```

In your program you access uninitialized memory because the first argument by all definition ends after the first `'\0'`. The result are probably deterministic but essentially undefined.

Comment: When I try that, the output is `01 02 01 0a`

Comment: So in this case it simply swallows the `\0`. Still, it doesn't change the fact that you cannot have zero bytes in an arguments string ...

Comment: I think shell doesn't perform something special with zero bytes. Basically my fault was that i used the 'hexdump -C test' to verify the input, but what is actually transfered by the shell is 'cat test'. Because of zero bytes aren't printable they have dissapeared.

Comment: I was even thinking about encoding issues, because python's `print` picks up the console's default encoding when writing to `stdout`. But it's really just undefined behaviour.